# How to plot correct pdf from embed image dwg

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

Please tell me how to plot correct pdf from embed image dwg.

I am evaluating Design Automation plot from the dwg with enbed image.
I recieved black filled dwg on below condition.

- Dasign Automation API version:v2
- AppPackage:PlotToPDF
- DWG:[rasterTest.dwg](https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-forge/rasterTest.dwg)
- AutoCAD version: 23.0(P.45.Z.36)

Also I tried my original plot apppackage, 
and the result was the pdf filled black .

Comment: I can reproduce this problem. I doubt if export to PDF with rast image requires to have the drawing open visibly, so tried to test with local acccoreconsole, but it throws another error. I will need to check with engineer team.

Answer (score 0):

The default PlotToPDF activity is defined as follows:

`_tilemode 0 -export _pdf _all result.pdf\n`

This means it only plot paperspace. This drawing has no initialized paperspace layouts. You can  do 2 things.

1. Use a different script that plots the current space.

```
   AutoCAD PDF (General Documentation).pc3
   e:\test.pdf
   _N
   _Y
```

2. Resave the drawing so that it has an initialized layout.